# Is there a better way to calculate this probability?

Tags: java, math, probability

So i've been wondering what is the probablity of that in a group of people at least one person has a birthday today.

I've came up with a solution like this:

```
private BigDecimal probability(BigDecimal peopleCount) {
    BigDecimal days = new BigDecimal("365");

    BigDecimal omega = days.pow(peopleCount.intValue());
    BigDecimal excluded = days.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(peopleCount.intValue());

    return omega.subtract(excluded).divide(omega, 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

And this seems to be calculating correctly but also looks like a bad solution - for 1000 people I need to calculate what is 365^1000 (some crazy numbers).

Does anyone know a better (cleaner) way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: So if I read your code correctly, the formula is `(d^p-(d-1)^p)/d^p`. My first thought is that you could factor...but the bases are different. The only way I can see to try to reduce this is to first expand `(d-1)^p`, but that requires the binomial formula and will quickly become a huge mess.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it is indeed a programming question because it is about how to implement a given formula.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no need to factor or apply the binomial formula. Just divide through by `d^p` so you get `1 - ((d - 1)/d)^p` which is the formula shown by Alan below.

Comment: Well, given that the formula is set, "cleaner" is subjective. It seems like OP has an aesthetic distaste for computing 365^1000, but that's not really avoidable - altering the order of divisions and multiplications doesn't really change anything. The choice between arbitrary-precision decimal, a rational number implementation or ordinary floating-point also depends on requirements outside the question statement and is also out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The probability of at least one having it is 1.0 minus the probability of nobody having a birthday.

The prob one person **not** having a birthday, or 364/365 = a.

The prob of all 1000 not having (equals nobody having) is the prob of each multiplied together = a^1000.

The answer is 1.0 - (364/365)^1000.

If we count leap years for Feb 29 and the other un-leap years that would ordinarily be leap years we get a finely tuned number near 365.25 but not exactly.  That can be the denominator.